# jQuery replacewith anchor tag to span tag

Tags: jquery, attr, replacewith

I'm trying to have an anchor tag removed and replaced with a span tag but keep the class attr.  I have this code but it is showing "undefined" for the class.

```
$("#wprmenu_menu").find('li:has(ul) > a').replaceWith(function() {
    var Qthis = $(this);
    var className = Qthis.attr('class');
    return $("<span class=\"" + className + "\">" + Qthis.html() + "</span>");
});
```

the anchor tag gets removed, and the text inside stays but the class does not transfer over.

Comment: Do you have a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't see anything wrong with your code.
I made a simply assumption based on your selector.
Changed the escape to single quotes as well. Not affecting the outcome.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S3jZr/)

```
$("#wprmenu_menu").find('li:has(ul) > a').replaceWith(function() {
    var Qthis = $(this);
    var className = Qthis.attr('class');
    return $("<span class='" + className + "'>" + Qthis.html() + "</span>");
});
```

Comment: Thanks @tmcc for your response, sorry for my belated response.  This snippet did not end up being the issue, and I'm not sure at this point what the real issue was.  I do agree that it needed an easier to read quote syntax.  I have come a long way since then in JS, lol.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myButton').click(function(){
    $("#someDiv a").replaceWith(function(){
        return $("<span>" + $(this).html() + "</span>");
    });
});
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.